# Improve efficiency and fairness when combining temporally close events

Tags: c#, concurrency

I have a bunch of threads that generate events of type `A` and type `B`.

My program takes these events, wraps them in a message and sends them across the network. A message can hold either one `A` event, one `B` event, or one `A` event and one `B` event:

```
SendMessage(new Message(a: 1,    b: null));
SendMessage(new Message(a: null, b: 2   ));
SendMessage(new Message(a: 3,    b: 4   ));
```

Events of type `A` happen quite frequently, while events of type `B` occur much less often. So, when a thread generates a `B` event, my program waits a bit to see if another thread generates an `A` event and combines the `A` event and the `B` event if possible.

Here is my code:

```
object gate = new object();
int? pendingB;

Message WrapA(int a, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    int? b;

    lock (gate)
    {
        b = pendingB;
        pendingB = null;
        Monitor.Pulse(gate);
    }

    return new Message(a, b);
}

Message WrapB(int b, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    lock (gate)
    {
        if (pendingB == null)
        {
            pendingB = b;
            Monitor.Wait(gate, millisecondsTimeout);
            if (pendingB != b) return null;
            pendingB = null;
        }
    }

    return new Message(null, b);
}
```

This works so far. However, there are two problems:

- If there are lots of `A` events and lots of `B` events, the algorithm is not very efficient: Only a certain percentage of `B` events is attached to `A` events, even when there are enough `A` events.
- If there are no `A` events generated for a while (uncommon, but not impossible), the algorithm is completely unfair: One thread generating `B` events has to wait every time, while all other threads can send their `B` events right away.

How can I improve efficiency and fairness of the algorithm?

<sub>Constraints:

•  `WrapA` and `WrapB` must terminate within a short, deterministic amount of time.

•  `SendMessage` must be called outside any locks.

•  There is no synchronization mechanism available other than `gate`.

•  There are not additional threads, tasks, timers, etc. available.

•  Since events of type `A` happen so frequently in the normal case, busy-waiting in `WrapB` is fine.</sub>

---

Here is a test program that can be used as a benchmark:

```
public static class Program
{
    static int counter0 = 0;
    static int counterA = 0;
    static int counterB = 0;
    static int counterAB = 0;

    static void SendMessage(Message m)
    {
        if (m != null)
            if (m.a != null)
                if (m.b != null)
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref counterAB);
                else
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref counterA);
            else
                if (m.b != null)
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref counterB);
                else
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref counter0);
    }

    static Thread[] Start(int threadCount, int eventCount,
        int eventInterval, int wrapTimeout, Func<int, int, Message> wrap)
    {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadCount * eventCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < eventCount; j++)
            {
                int k = i * 1000 + j;
                int l = j * eventInterval + i;
                threads[i * eventCount + j] = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(l);
                    SendMessage(wrap(k, wrapTimeout));
                });
                threads[i * eventCount + j].Start();
            }
        }
        return threads;
    }

    static void Join(params Thread[] threads)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
        {
            threads[i].Join();
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wrapper = new MessageWrapper();
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        // Only A events
        var t0 = Start(10, 40, 7, 1000, wrapper.WrapA);
        Join(t0);

        // A and B events
        var t1 = Start(10, 40, 7, 1000, wrapper.WrapA);
        var t2 = Start(10, 10, 19, 1000, wrapper.WrapB);
        Join(t1);
        Join(t2);

        // Only B events
        var t3 = Start(10, 20, 7, 1000, wrapper.WrapB);
        Join(t3);

        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

        Console.WriteLine("0:  {0}", counter0);
        Console.WriteLine("A:  {0}", counterA);
        Console.WriteLine("B:  {0}", counterB);
        Console.WriteLine("AB: {0}", counterAB);

        Console.WriteLine("Generated A: {0}, Sent A: {1}",
            10 * 40 + 10 * 40, counterA + counterAB);
        Console.WriteLine("Generated B: {0}, Sent B: {1}",
            10 * 10 + 10 * 20, counterB + counterAB);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you have a compiling test project so we can play with it?

Comment: The algorithm is part of a larger program. It's difficult to provide example code that generates events in the same way the real code does. For the purpose of this question, you can just spin up a bunch up threads calling `WrapA` and `WrapB` and test with different numbers of threads and intervals between events.

Comment: I think such a sample program would be interesting, even for you, since the question is very "pure" and independent from other considerations. Anyway, your small test code doesn't uses the WrapA. How are these supposed to be combined with the WrapB since you have some kind or ratio between them? 'lot', 'few', 'for a while' are not very informative :-)

Comment: I've added an expanded test program. It measures the time it takes to generate and send a certain amount of events, and how many messages of each type are sent. You have to play a bit with the constants; for example, if you set `aThreadCount` to 0 then you see the fairness problem. I know that  'lot', 'few' and 'for a while' isn't very precise, but that's all I can say at them moment. If it turns out that the answer to this question doesn't perform well in the real word, that shall be my problem and not the answer's. I'll try to come up with a better benchmark program though.

Comment: I've added a new test program that can be used as a simple benchmark. It should cover all corner cases, but doesn't model the actual distribution of events very well. I think it should be good enough to compare different answers to this question.

Comment: So if A and B events are essentially independent, why even bother with combining them?

Comment: There is a cost associated with sending a message. I'd like to avoid the cost for a B-only message if I can merge it with an A-only message. Keeping the cost low is more important to me than a low latency for B events, although a low latency is a priority as well.

Comment: Is this a consumer-producer problem? You have several threads that generate events of type A and B (producers) and one (or more?) threads that send these events (consumers) – or do the producers send the messages themselves? If the former, did you think about queueing your messages and then let your consumer thread(s) pick items from the queue when they get available? There'd be several advantages to this approach – let me know if this would be acceptable and I'll formulate a more deatilled answer (also: which version of the .NET framework are you using?)

Comment: If I didn't want to combine events, then the producer threads would be completely independent and could send all messages themselves. There is no need for a consumer thread for the purpose of sending the messages. Note that I do not have additional threads nor space for an unbounded queue available. (I'm using .NET 4.5)

Comment: Is the cost of doing new Message(null, null) important? Is it just possible? I mean can we send these without impacting your system?

Comment: A Message(null, null) is used to signal that all events have been generated, so it must not be sent when there are still messages to come.

Comment: Actually it's too bad some of the constraints are required. With BlockingCollection<T> and an extra thread the processing went from 22s to 1.67s on my VM (0: 0, A: 700, B: 11, AB: 100, 0:0:1.678s). Possibly you can (re) implement the code so that it doesn't use an additional thread and synchronizes to 'gate'.

Comment: That's what makes this problem so tricky :-) With an unbounded queue and an additional thread for merging events, this would be really simple.

Comment: Looks like you changed the test program in the middle of the game!

Comment: Interestingly enough, your own solution does not fullfill the first requirement since it is using an unrestricted 'lock'. A simple fix would be to use 'Monitor.TryEnter .. Monitor.Exit', that way you can set a timeout on the lock as well.

Comment: I personally am a big fan of the Rx.Net library, which contrary to what many people think. Multithreading isn't the default behavior. However in order to implement this piece of code I would have to implicitly use a Timer. But my understanding is that MultExs are highly inefficient. I was wondering if you would consider using that library.

Comment: +1 for a fun and interesting problem. But where do these constraints come from? Are you actually coding for an embedded device or some other limited Environment?

Comment: There is a problem with your sample test code - you are starting all threads in place, so for AB test, by the time you create all threads responsible for sending B events, some of A threads are already done.

Comment: You can check it for yourself adding quite simple code to store time when A and B was sent for the first time (using Interlocked.CompareExchange) and for the last time (using simple Exchange). 
I think on really fast machines the problem becomes even worse. So I would add some synchronisation to test threads, for example CountdownEvent so they all start (almost) at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the fun of it, here is a lock-free implementation:

```
public sealed class MessageWrapper
{
    private int pendingB;

    public Message WrapA(int a, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        int b = Interlocked.Exchange(ref pendingB, -1);
        return new Message(a, b == -1 ? null : b);
    }

    public Message WrapB(int b, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        var sw = new SpinWait();
        while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref pendingB, b, -1) != -1)
        {
            // Spin
            sw.SpinOnce();

            if (sw.NextSpinWillYield)
            {
                // Let us make progress instead of yielding the processor
                // (avoid context switch)
                return new Message(null, b);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Results**

Original implementation:

```
00:00:02.0433298
0:  0
A:  733
B:  233
AB: 67
Generated A: 800, Sent A: 800
Generated B: 300, Sent B: 300
```

Lock-free implementation:

```
00:00:01.2546310
0:  0
A:  717
B:  217
AB: 83
Generated A: 800, Sent A: 800
Generated B: 300, Sent B: 300
```

**Update**

Unfortunately, above implementation has a bug plus some shortcoming. Here is an improved version:

```
public class MessageWrapper
{
    private int pendingB = EMPTY;
    private const int EMPTY = -1;

    public Message WrapA(int a, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        int? b;
        int count = 0;
        while ((b = Interlocked.Exchange(ref pendingB, EMPTY)) == EMPTY)
        {
            if (count % 7 == 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
            else if (count % 23 == 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Yield();
            }
            if (++count == 480)
            {
                return new Message(a, null);
            }
        }
        return new Message(a, b);
    }

    public Message WrapB(int b, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref pendingB, b, EMPTY) != EMPTY)
        {
            // Spin
            Thread.SpinWait((4 << count++));
            if (count > 10)
            {
                // We didn't manage to place our payload.
                // Let's send it ourselves:
                return new Message(null, b);
            }
        }

        // We placed our payload. 
        // Wait some more to see if some WrapA snatches it.
        while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref pendingB, EMPTY, EMPTY) == b)
        {
            Thread.SpinWait((4 << count++));
            if (count > 20)
            {
                // No WrapA came along. Pity, we will have to send it ourselves
                int payload = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref pendingB, EMPTY, b);
                return payload == b ? new Message(null, b) : null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Results:

OP's implementation

```
00:00:02.1389474
0:  0
A:  722
B:  222
AB: 78
Generated A: 800, Sent A: 800
Generated B: 300, Sent B: 300
```

Second implementation:

```
00:00:01.2752425
0:  0
A:  700
B:  200
AB: 100
Generated A: 800, Sent A: 800
Generated B: 300, Sent B: 300
```

Comment: Neat. And if you change it to use SpinUntil() you can honor the timeout as well, and would fullfill the constraint on deterministic exeution :-)

Comment: Actually, above implementation is deterministic. Each thread that enters the WrapB method will spin for a maximum of 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + 1024 + 2048 + 4096 = 8188 iterations on a multi processor system (and not at all on a single processor system). After that the `NextSpinWillYield` property will return true and the thread will return from the method call.

Comment: That's interesting, where did you find those numbers? MSDN only states "On machines with multiple CPUs, SpinOnce may yield after an unspecified number of calls."

Comment: In the SpinWait.cs source code. ;-) Note, that "unspecified" does not mean "random". The actual number of iterations is an implementation detail that may change in the future, so it is not specified in the documentation. The number of iterations increases exponentially with each call to `SpinWait.SpinOnce()`. Internally SpinWait keeps a counter (accessible via `SpinWait.Count`) and on each call to `SpinWait.SpinOnce()` the thread spins for `4 << m_count`, unless `NextSpinWillYield` returns true which is the case if (a) the code is executing on a single processor machine or...

Comment: (b) m_count > YIELD_THRESHOLD (which is set to 10 in the current implementation). After that limit has been reached SpinWait.SpinOnce will call `Thread.Yield()`, `Thread.Sleep(0)`, and `Thread.Sleep(1)`.

Comment: Btw. if you are interested in all the details of the SpinWait implementation, I can't recommend Joe Duffy's "Concurrent Programming On Windows" highly enough (see chapter 14, section "Spin Waiting").

Comment: What about `millisecondsTimeout`? I can't see implementation for it. But generally, it looks interesting.

Comment: I don't need it or rather: I don't want to use it. Maybe I will add some explanatory comments to the answer later today.

Comment: Have you considered having 'pendingB' and the sentinel value defined as longs? That would make it possible to pass an int without any restrictions.

Answer (score 5):

For diversity, I tried an approach based on the concurrent collections. To me it's not clear from the posted constraints whether that is okay but I'll shoot my answer anyway:

This is the typical output from your original code on my machine:

```
00:00:01.7835426
0:  0
A:  723
B:  223
AB: 77
Generated A: 800, Sent A: 800
Generated B: 300, Sent B: 300
```

This is the typical output from my suggestion, about 20% slower than the original code but it captures more 'AB' messages:

```
00:00:02.1322512
0:  0
A:  701
B:  201
AB: 99
Generated A: 800, Sent A: 800
Generated B: 300, Sent B: 300
```

MessageWrapper implementation:

```
public class MessageWrapper
{
    private BlockingCollection<int?> messageA = new BlockingCollection<int?>();
    private BlockingCollection<int?> messageB = new BlockingCollection<int?>();

    public Message WrapA(int a, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        messageA.Add(a);
        return CreateMessage(0);
    }

    public Message WrapB(int b, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        messageB.Add(b);
        return CreateMessage(millisecondsTimeout);
    }

    private Message CreateMessage(int timeout)
    {
        int? a, b;

        if (messageB.TryTake(out b) | messageA.TryTake(out a, timeout))
        {
            return new Message(a, b);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a perfect candidate for [Reactive Extesions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx). You can use the [Buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229308%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) method to group events or other similar extensions to filter and combine events.

Maybe this solution doesn't match one of your constraint but in my opinion it's the best solution. Reactive Extensions are very powerful.

Comment: I would definitely give Reactive Extensions a try. v2.0 should be reasonably fast and able to work very good with deterministic time handling. Rx create their own threads and timers, so this constraint is broken, but hopefully it's not a hard, system constraint

Answer (score 1):

I'll give another suggestion that follows the given constraints a bit more strictly; on my machine this implementation consistently catches 97 or more 'AB' messages when running the test program, with about 5% performance degradation from the original code:

```
class MessageWrapper
{
    object gate = new object();
    int? pendingB;

    public Message WrapA(int a, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        Message returnMessage = null;
        bool lockTaken = false;

        Monitor.TryEnter(gate, 100, ref lockTaken);

        if (lockTaken)
        {
            returnMessage = new Message(a, pendingB);

            pendingB = null;
            Monitor.Pulse(gate);

            Monitor.Exit(gate);
        }
        else
        {
            returnMessage = new Message(a, null);
        }

        return returnMessage;
    }

    public Message WrapB(int b, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        Message returnMessage = null;
        bool lockTaken = false;

        Monitor.TryEnter(gate, 100, ref lockTaken);

        if (lockTaken)
        {
            if (pendingB != null)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(gate, 100);
            }

            if (pendingB != null)
            {
                returnMessage = new Message(null, b);
            }
            else
            {
                pendingB = b;

                if (!Monitor.Wait(gate, millisecondsTimeout))
                {
                    pendingB = null;
                    Monitor.Pulse(gate);
                    returnMessage = new Message(null, b);
                }
            }

            Monitor.Exit(gate);
        }
        else
        {
            returnMessage = new Message(null, b);
        }

        return returnMessage;
    }
}
```

What's happening here is basically the same as in the original code, but we're also waiting when there is already a *pendingB* object instead of just returning a 'B' message. This improves the amount of 'AB' messages that we can find, at a small performance cost.

It looks a bit messy, but it's mostly because I opted to use the more real-time friendly construct *Monitor.TryTake* instead of a raw *lock*. Also, having a single *return* statement is a neat trick to avoid deadlocks from accidentally returning before calling *Monitor.Exit*.

Fiddling with the various timeouts can improve performance at the cost of accuracy, or vice versa. 100ms was my initial guess for all, and it looks decent on my machine at least.

---

As a final note, in this implementation of *WrapB* we could change the lines

```
            if (pendingB != null)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(gate, 100);
            }
```

to

```
            while (pendingB != null)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(gate, 100);
            }
```

to get 100% accuracy, but it severely messes up the metrics from the test program since it synchronizes the 'B' events which obviously performs extremely poorly when there is a stream of only 'B' messages.

If I remove the *t3* test, this runs about 5% *faster* than the original code while consistently finding 100 out of 100 'AB' messages. But then the runtime is of course no longer deterministic since we can't tell how many times we'll spin around the loop.

Edit:

Well, unless we do something like

```
            int spinCount = 0;

            while (pendingB != null && spinCount < 5)
            {
                spinCount++;
                Monitor.Wait(gate, 100);
            }
```

which will give us an upper bound on the wait time. It does solve the performance problems when we have a stream of only 'B' messages, and runs in about the same time as your original code while consistently finding 100 out of 100 'AB' messages.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I tried to create a Fast A and AB and then a slow B. This means that my overall time is slower (mainly because of the b-only stream), but the combined time and a-only time is faster. Here are the results:

```
A's only: 00:00:00.3975499
Combine: 00:00:00.4234934
B's only: 00:00:02.0079422
Total: 00:00:02.8314751
0:  0
A:  700
B:  200
AB: 100
Generated A: 800, Sent A: 800
Generated B: 300, Sent B: 300
```

Here's the code:

```
    class MessageWrapper
    {
        object bMessageLock = new object();
        object pendingBLock = new object();
        int? pendingB;

        ManualResetEvent gateOpen = new ManualResetEvent(true); // Gate is open initially.


        private bool IsGateOpen()
        {
            return gateOpen.WaitOne(0);
        }

        private void OpenGate()
        {
            gateOpen.Set();
        }

        private void CloseGate()
        {
            gateOpen.Reset();
        }


        public Message WrapA(int a, int millisecondsTimeout)
        {
            // check if the gate is open. Use WaitOne(0) to return immediately.
            if (IsGateOpen())
            {
                return new Message(a, null);
            }
            else
            {
                // This extra lock is to make sure that we don't get stale b's.
                lock (pendingBLock)
                {
                    // and reopen the gate.
                    OpenGate();

                    // there is a waiting b
                    // Send combined message
                    var message = new Message(a, pendingB);

                    pendingB = null;

                    return message;
                }
            }
        }

        public Message WrapB(int b, int millisecondsTimeout)
        {

            // Remove this if you don't have overlapping B's
            var timespentInLock = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            lock (bMessageLock) // Only one B message can be sent at a time.... may need to fix this.
            {
                pendingB = b;

                // Close gate
                CloseGate();


                // Wait for the gate to be opened again (meaning that the message has been sent)
                if (timespentInLock.ElapsedMilliseconds < millisecondsTimeout && 
                    gateOpen.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout - (int)timespentInLock.ElapsedMilliseconds)) 
                // If you don't have overlapping b's use this clause instead.
                //if (gateOpen.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout)) 
                {
                    lock (pendingBLock)
                    {
                        // Gate was opened, so combined message was sent.
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Timeout expired, so send b-only message.
                    lock (pendingBLock)
                    {
                        // reopen gate.
                        OpenGate();
                        pendingB = null;
                        return new Message(null, b);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

The main work is done my using a manual reset event. The idea is that if the gate is open, then you can send A's freely. When a 'b' arrives, you close the gate and force A to combine it. I must say that having a single `pendingB` field restricts this operation somewhat. Having only one variable means that only one thread can store it's b in pendingB. This is why I have the extra `bMessageLock`.

Also, access to this variable needs to be controlled, hence the `pendingBLock`.

There may still be bugs in this code, but as much as I test it, I still get all 100 messages combined.

Lastly, I included the check against the time that WrapB was waiting. Originally the WrapB's would just queue up taking a total of 200 seconds. If you have overlapping calls, then you can add the check. If you don't mind them queuing up, use the simpler code instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my first ideea would be to have a semaphore that also handles priority, but maybe this post will give you more insight [.Net Mutex Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978893/net-mutex-question)

Basically the ideea would be to have some way to prioritize the 2 types of events so that events of type `B` can run as fast a possible if no events of type `A` are received.

I realise this might not be the right solution for you because of your third constraint that no sync mechanism other than Gate is available but i hope that I might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I already have sort of a queue in my code: `pendingB` is a queue with space for one item. `B` events cannot run as fast as `A` events, because `B` events wait for `A` events. But there is only one `B` event waiting. I just want to improve fairness. I don't see how your answer helps, but thanks for giving it a try.

Comment: @dtb I was thinking about removing the wait on `B` events and rely on a queue that processes them, but that queue will always look to give priority to `A` if they have been received within a short timeframe of one another for instance, else process the `B` event that is next in queue. So in essence, move the locking mechanism one step up scope-wise and handle what event should be Wrapped and sent next based on the priority from a queue that each event will be put in.

Comment: Such a queue would require another thread that processes it, right? I don't have such another thread available. And I don't have space for an unbounded queue. It's tricky :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is a sketch of an approach that improves fairness - it will mean that *all* `B`-sends are subject to a delay of up to 100ms. I don't know however if it fits with your constraints.

- In a global context, have a single `MessageSender` object of type `IMessageSender`
- There are two implementations of `IMessageSender`, namely `DefaultMessageSender`, and `BWrappingMessageSender` (which stores a `b` value)

The message senders behaviour is as follows:

- `DefaultMessageSender` on being asked to send an `A`: just sends it
- `DefaultMessageSender` on being asked to send an `B`: switches the global `MessageSender` to being a new `BWrappingMessageSender` which knows the just-passed value `b`
- `BWrappingMessageSender` on being asked to send an `A`: sends an AB with the passed `a` and its own `b`, and switches the global `MessageSender` to being a `DefaultMessageSender`
- `BWrappingMessageSender` on being asked to send a `B`: sends a `B` with its own `b`, and switches the global `MessageSender` to being a new `BWrappingMessageSender` which knows the just-passed value `b`

What I haven't pinned down is a way that a newly-created `BWrappingMessageSender` knows to send a plain `B` 100ms after being created, if it hasn't in that time been told to do anything else.

Comment: Let BWrappingMessageSender start a timer when it's created. When it's asked to send an `A`, send A with pending B and stop the timer. When it's asked to send a B, send pending B and stop the timer and create BWrappingMessageSender with new B. When the timer fires, send pending B and switch back to DefaultMessageSender. The only problem is: I don't have a timer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution after some experimentation:

- If the single-element queue is empty, we take the spot.
- If the spot is already taken, we politely nudge the occupant to move on, wait a bit and try again.
- If someone is rude and hijacks the spot while we're waiting, we jump the queue and move on.

*Code:*

```
Message WrapA(int a, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    bool lockTaken = false;
    int? b = null;

    try
    {
        Monitor.TryEnter(gate, millisecondsTimeout, ref lockTaken);
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            if (pendingB != null)
            {
                b = pendingB;
                pendingB = null;
                Monitor.Pulse(gate);
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(gate);
        }
    }

    return new Message(a, b);
}

Message WrapB(int b, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    bool lockTaken = false;

    try
    {
        TimeoutHelper timeout = new TimeoutHelper(millisecondsTimeout);
        Monitor.TryEnter(gate, timeout.RemainingTime(), ref lockTaken);
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            if (pendingB == null)
            {
                pendingB = b;
                Monitor.Wait(gate, timeout.RemainingTime());
                if (pendingB == null) return null;
                pendingB = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Monitor.Pulse(gate);
                try { }
                finally { lockTaken = false; Monitor.Exit(gate); }
                Thread.Sleep(1);
                Monitor.TryEnter(gate, timeout.RemainingTime(), ref lockTaken);
                if (lockTaken)
                {
                    if (pendingB == null)
                    {
                        pendingB = b;
                        Monitor.Wait(gate, timeout.RemainingTime());
                        if (pendingB == null) return null;
                        pendingB = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(gate);
        }
    }

    return new Message(null, b);
}
```

Comment: This solves the fairness problem, but has some room for improvement regarding efficiency. Can this be further improved so more `B` events are combined with `A` events when enough of both are generated?

Comment: A struct that remembers a deadline=now+timeout in its constructor and tells you how much time until the deadline is left. See https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus/TimeoutHelper.cs or https://ssbwcf.svn.codeplex.com/svn/SsbTransportChannel/TimeoutHelper.cs

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it does what you want, but here is my proposition. It basically hands off any B message to A whenever possible, and checks the message has been sent after all:

```
class MessageWrapper
{
    object gate = new object();
    int? pendingB;

    public Message WrapA(int a, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        int? b;

        lock (gate)
        {
            b = pendingB;
            pendingB = null;
            Thread.Sleep(1); // yield. 1 seems the best value after some testing
        }

        return new Message(a, b);
    }

    public Message WrapB(int b, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        int? bb = b;

        lock (gate)
        {
            if (pendingB == null)
            {
                pendingB = b;
                bb = null;
            }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(3);

        if (bb == null)
        {
            lock (gate)
            {
                if (pendingB != null)
                {
                    bb = pendingB;
                    pendingB = null;
                }
            }
        }
        return new Message(null, bb);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try! I've plugged it into the above test program, and it seems there is a small bug: one of the B events isn't sent. Apart from that, it's a great improvement (78 AB messages) over my original solution (43 AB messages) and the solution in my answer (32 AB messages out of 100 possible).

Comment: Yes, I've seen that small bug. The last B just stays stored in pendingB and nobody ever gets it, but I suppose your real program just does that continuously, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: In my real program it's okay if a B event gets a bit delayed, but it's not okay if gets delayed too much, i.e., all events must be sent within a small, deterministic amount of time. So, with this bug, this solution unfortunately doesn't work for me.

Comment: Well, it really depends on what's your real program is in the end, but I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works. The trick seems to be the `Thread.Sleep(1);` in `WrapA`. If I move it outside the `lock`, the number of AB messages goes significantly down. Any idea why is that so? Also, increasing the `Thread.Sleep(3);` in `WrapB` does not seem to increase the number of AB messages. Anyway, your answer inspired me to [another solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983713/improve-efficiency-and-fairness-when-combining-temporally-close-events#15043109) which shows very promising results (88 AB messages out of 100).

Comment: Thread.Sleep() will yield this thread execution, so indirectly transfer execution to any other thread waiting. If you put it in a lock, you can pass execution from a thread in a lock to another thread (even if it's also in a lock).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another attempt. The approach is to wait for the generation of an `A` event to attach to a `B` event, instead of waiting for a `B` event to get attached to an `A` event.

```
object gate = new object();
int? pendingA;

public Message WrapA(int a, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    bool queued = false;

    lock (gate)
    {
        if (pendingA == null)
        {
            queued = true;
            pendingA = a;
            Monitor.Pulse(gate);
        }
    }

    if (queued)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3);
        lock (gate)
        {
            if (pendingA == null)
                return null;

            a = pendingA.Value;
            pendingA = null;
        }
    }

    return new Message(a, null);
}

public Message WrapB(int b, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    int? a;

    lock (gate)
    {
        if (pendingA == null)
            Monitor.Wait(gate, millisecondsTimeout);

        a = pendingA;
        pendingA = null;
    }

    return new Message(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but it takes 20 seconds total to complete :-). It's always a compromise between total time vs number of AB sent. You can wait forever and send 100% of possible AB.

Answer (score 0):

After three hours of trying, I managed to get the following results:

```
00:00:01.8577304
0:  0
A:  741
B:  241
AB: 59
Generated A: 800, Sent A: 800
Generated B: 300, Sent B: 300
Total: 1100
```

My method:

**(1)** Whenever there's a message B (from now called B) and there is not yet a B waiting, it will put it to the 'queue'. If there's no other packet within the given timeout, it will send the message. **(2)** When there is actually a B in the queue, it will bump off the first B in the queue and will send this message. This is to ensure fairness. The new B, that is being send will follow the same situation as situation 1 (it will be queued, and send within the given amount of time). **(3)** When there's a message A (from now called A), and there's no pending B, A will be sent immediately. No actual waiting is performed. **(4)** When sending A and there's a B in the queue, it will 'steal' it from the queue. Both messages are wrapped, and are sent together. Because B is waiting to be sent on the other thread, and A stole it, we need a null check. A will notify B, but B notices it has nothing to send. B will return null.

To accomplish this in code:

```
public class MessageWrapper
{
    readonly object _gate = new object();
    int? _pendingB;

    public Message WrapA(int a, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        int? currentB;

        lock (_gate)
        {
            currentB = _pendingB;
            _pendingB = null;

            Monitor.Pulse(_gate); // B stolen, get rid of waiting threads
        }

        return new Message(a, currentB);
    }

    public Message WrapB(int b, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        lock (_gate)
        {
            if (_pendingB != null)
            {
                var currentB = _pendingB;
                _pendingB = b;

                Monitor.Pulse(_gate); // release for fairness
                Monitor.Wait(_gate, millisecondsTimeout); // wait for fairness

                return new Message(null, currentB);
            }
            else
            {
                _pendingB = b;

                Monitor.Pulse(_gate); // release for fairness
                Monitor.Wait(_gate, millisecondsTimeout); // wait for A

                if (_pendingB == null) return null;

                var currentB = _pendingB;
                _pendingB = null;
                return new Message(null, currentB);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Three hours... wow. Thanks for putting so much effort into this! I'll copy it into my program and see how it performs.

Comment: Anytime. I couldn't get the highlighting in the codeblock right. I guess it's only allowed to post one class?

Comment: Just indent the code; `<pre>` tags are not necessary. I removed a few bits of the code that are not relevant; it's fine if one of the methods just returns `null` instead of a message.

Answer (score 0):

Great problem. I really enjoyed spending some time on this. The solution that I used had 4 times the amount of matches that your original problem resulted with on my computer hardware.

Perhaps someone that is more knowledgeable than I am with Monitor and locks can improve this.

1. Release another thread when a match is made instead of having that thread do a full sleep just to return null in the end. Perhaps this really is not that costly though. To solve this I introduced the AutoResetEvent, but for reasons that I do not understand, the AutoResetEvent is not acting as I intended and reduces the matches from 100 to 70.
2. The final timeout of threads can be improved since once it times out it still needs to pass a contested lock.

It does fully fit the requirements:

1. All processes will terminate within the specified period of time (The last lock may add a few cycles depending on how contested the lock is).
2. Sending is outside of the locks.
3. Synchronizes using gate
4. No extra timers
5. Preference and threads are treated equally

Original Questions Results:

1. Time: 4.5 seconds
2. A: 773
3. B: 273
4. AB: 27

This Classes Results:

1. Time: 5.4 seconds
2. A: 700
3. B: 300
4. AB: 100

   ```
   class MessageWrapper
   {
   object gate = new object();
   int EmptyThreadsToReleaseA = 0;
   int EmptyThreadsToReleaseB = 0;
   Queue<int> queueA = new Queue<int>();
   Queue<int> queueB = new Queue<int>();
   AutoResetEvent EmptyThreadEventA = new AutoResetEvent(false);
   AutoResetEvent EmptyThreadEventB = new AutoResetEvent(false);

   public Message WrapA(int a, int millisecondsTimeout)
   {
       lock (gate)
       {
           if (queueB.Count > 0)
           {
               Interlocked.Increment(ref EmptyThreadsToReleaseB);
               EmptyThreadEventB.Set();
               return new Message(a, queueB.Dequeue());
           }
           else
           {
               queueA.Enqueue(a);
           }
       }

       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout);
       //EmptyThreadEventA.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout);

       lock (gate)
       {
           if (EmptyThreadsToReleaseA > 0)
           {
               Interlocked.Decrement(ref EmptyThreadsToReleaseA);
               return null;
           }

           return new Message(queueA.Dequeue(), null);
       }
   }

   public Message WrapB(int b, int millisecondsTimeout)
   {
       lock (gate)
       {
           if (queueA.Count > 0)
           {
               Interlocked.Increment(ref EmptyThreadsToReleaseA);
               EmptyThreadEventA.Set();
               return new Message(queueA.Dequeue(), b);
           }
           else
           {
               queueB.Enqueue(b);
           }
       }

       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout);
       //EmptyThreadEventB.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout);

       lock (gate)
       {
           if (EmptyThreadsToReleaseB > 0)
           {
               Interlocked.Decrement(ref EmptyThreadsToReleaseB);
               return null;
           }

           return new Message(null, queueB.Dequeue());
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: The huge drawback on these 'wait' approaches, is you have to wait a long time for everything to complete. In this case, it's 1m35s.

Comment: Perhaps you do not fully understand my comment? I'm just saying it takes 1m35s to complete.

Comment: Sorry about the above message, it sounds crass, I was cut short before I was finished typing....

Comment: The time to complete was 7 seconds, not 1m35. As for the problem, to match data, there must be a specified amount of time. Otherwise there would never be enough time for the pieces of data to match. This amount of time is specified by the timeout. In the method above, the only time that the wrapper "waits" is when there is not matching data, and the amount of time that each independent piece of data waits is equal to the timeout. Also each wrappers type can have a different timeout, so if you would like only "MessageB" type to wait. Then specify the A timeout as 0.

Comment: Please also note that matched pairs are immediately released and do not wait.

Comment: That's strange. On my machine, my code runs runs in 1sec total (for ~70 AB), while yours in 1m35s (for 100 AB) (compiled in X86).

Comment: That is strange. Perhaps we have a different test case? I tested yours with the results of 5.3 Seconds and 9-17 matches on average. Mine came out at 5.3 seconds and 100 matches. I am using the test case posted by dtb. Perhaps someone else can test my method.

Comment: Ok, I know what's going on. The OP's test program has been changed! I was still running on the old program. I can't work on a moving target... :-)

Comment: Haha, glad to hear that we cleared that up ;-). Thanks for your help. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to avoid unnecessary locks, especially for events of type A. Also I've made some changes in the logic of wrapper class. I've found that it would be more convenient to send messages directly from this class instead of just returning messages, that's because in my implementation a single call to `SendB` could potentially send two B messages.
I've put some explaining comments in code

```cs
public class MessageWrapper
{
    private readonly object _gate = new object();
    private object _pendingB;

    public void SendA(int a, int millisecondsTimeout, Action<Message> send)
    {
        var b = Interlocked.Exchange<object>(ref _pendingB, null);

        send(new Message(a, (int?)b));

        // this code will just release any pending "assure that B was sent" threads.
        // but everything works fine even without it
        lock (_gate)
        {
            Monitor.PulseAll(_gate);
        }
    }

    public void SendB(int b, int millisecondsTimeout, Action<Message> send)
    {
        // needed for Interlocked to function properly and to be able to chack that exatly this b event was sent.
        var boxedB = (object)(int?)b;

        // excange currently pending B event with newly arrived one
        var enqueuedB = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _pendingB, boxedB);

        if (enqueuedB != null)
        {
            // if there was some pending B event then just send it.
            send(new Message(null, (int?)enqueuedB));
        }

        // now we have to wait up to millisecondsTimeout to ensure that our message B was sent
        lock (_gate)
        {
            // release any currently waiting threads.
            Monitor.PulseAll(_gate);

            if (Monitor.Wait(_gate, millisecondsTimeout))
            {
                // if we there pulsed, then we have nothing to do, as our event was already sent 
                return;
            }
        }

        // check whether our event is still pending 
        enqueuedB = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _pendingB, null, boxedB);

        if (ReferenceEquals(enqueuedB, boxedB))
        {
            // if so, then just send it.
            send(new Message(null, (int?)enqueuedB));
        }
    }
}
```

Also I've maid some changes in your test class, one reason I've mentioned in comments - I've added synchronization event to all test threads for case when we testing AB clause. Also I've reduced number of  simultaneously running threads from 500 in your version, to 20 (that all for AB clause). Still calls in all these threads are shifted by the number of thread (passed as parameter in thread Start method), so I hope test is still quite relevant.

```cs
public static class Program
{
    private static int _counter0 = 0;
    private static int _counterA = 0;
    private static int _counterB = 0;
    private static int _counterAb = 0;
    private static object _lastA;
    private static object _lastB;

    private static object _firstA;
    private static object _firstB;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wrapper = new MessageWrapper();
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var threadsCount = 10;
        var a0called = 40;

        // Only A events
        var t0 = Start(threadsCount, a0called, 7, 1000, wrapper.SendA);
        Join(t0);

        var aJointCalled = 40;
        var bJointCalled = 10;

        var syncEvent = new CountdownEvent(threadsCount + threadsCount);
        _firstA = null;
        _firstB = null;
        // A and B events
        var t1 = Start(threadsCount, aJointCalled, 7, 1000, wrapper.SendA, syncEvent);
        var t2 = Start(threadsCount, bJointCalled, 19, 1000, wrapper.SendB, syncEvent);
        Join(t1);
        Join(t2);
        var lastA = _lastA;
        var lastB = _lastB;

        var b0called = 20;

        // Only B events
        var t3 = Start(threadsCount, b0called, 7, 1000, wrapper.SendB);
        Join(t3);

        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

        Console.WriteLine("0:  {0}", _counter0);
        Console.WriteLine("A:  {0}", _counterA);
        Console.WriteLine("B:  {0}", _counterB);
        Console.WriteLine("AB: {0}", _counterAb);

        Console.WriteLine(
            "Generated A: {0}, Sent A: {1}",
            (threadsCount * a0called) + (threadsCount * aJointCalled),
            _counterA + _counterAb);
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Generated B: {0}, Sent B: {1}",
            (threadsCount * bJointCalled) + (threadsCount * b0called),
            _counterB + _counterAb);

        Console.WriteLine("First A was sent on {0: MM:hh:ss ffff}", _firstA);
        Console.WriteLine("Last A was sent on {0: MM:hh:ss ffff}", lastA);
        Console.WriteLine("First B was sent on {0: MM:hh:ss ffff}", _firstB);
        Console.WriteLine("Last B was sent on {0: MM:hh:ss ffff}", lastB);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void SendMessage(Message m)
    {
        if (m != null)
        {
            if (m.A != null)
            {
                if (m.B != null)
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _counterAb);
                }
                else
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _counterA);
                    Interlocked.Exchange(ref _lastA, DateTime.Now);
                    Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _firstA, DateTime.Now, null);
                }
            }
            else if (m.B != null)
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _counterB);
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref _lastB, DateTime.Now);
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _firstB, DateTime.Now, null);
            }
            else
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter0);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Thread[] Start(
        int threadCount, 
        int eventCount, 
        int eventInterval, 
        int wrapTimeout, 
        Action<int, int, Action<Message>> wrap,
        CountdownEvent syncEvent = null)
    {
        var threads = new Thread[threadCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new Thread(
                (p) =>
                    {
                        if (syncEvent != null)
                        {
                            syncEvent.Signal();
                            syncEvent.Wait();
                        }

                        Thread.Sleep((int)p);

                        for (int j = 0; j < eventCount; j++)
                        {
                            int k = (((int)p) * 1000) + j;
                            Thread.Sleep(eventInterval);
                            wrap(k, wrapTimeout, SendMessage);
                        }
                    });

            threads[i].Start(i);
        }

        return threads;
    }

    private static void Join(params Thread[] threads)
    {
        foreach (Thread t in threads)
        {
            t.Join();
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Besides, thanks for really interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

The limiting factor on this is really the constraints, particularly the requirement of only using `gate` for synchronization and the inability to spawn any other timer/threads/tasks, etc. This ultimately ties a programming solution to use the `Monitor` objects. E.g., Christoffer's solution although elegant, technically uses synchronization other than `gate` as it's wrapped within the internals of `BlockingCollection`. The other very innovative solution listed previously by afrischke also uses synchronization other than `gate`.

After a lot of experimentation and reading and research I have to say that I don't think this problem has a better (faster?) solution that meets the constraints exactly. I managed to get marginal performance gain using the following mechanism. It's not pretty but it meets the requirements and is about 1-5% faster on average at least on my machine;

```
object gate = new object();
ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, int> _bBag = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, int>();

public Message WrapA(int a, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    Message message = null;
    int? b = null;
    lock (gate)
    {
        if (!_bBag.IsEmpty)
        {
            Guid key = _bBag.Keys.FirstOrDefault();
            int gotB = 0;
            if (_bBag.TryRemove(key, out gotB))
            {
                b = gotB;
                Monitor.PulseAll(gate);
            }
        }
    }

    message = new Message(a, b);
    return message;
}

public Message WrapB(int b, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    Guid key = Guid.NewGuid();
    _bBag.TryAdd(key, b);
    lock (gate) { Monitor.Wait(gate, millisecondsTimeout); }
    int storedB = 0;
    if (_bBag.TryRemove(key, out storedB))
    {
        return new Message(null, b);
    }
    return null;    
}
```

Relaxing the `gate` requirement improves the speed by another little bit, particularly when not running in debug mode;

```
object gate = new object();
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false /*initialState*/);
ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, int> _bBag = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, int>();

public Message WrapA(int a, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    Message message = null;
    int? b = null;
    lock (gate)
    {
        if (!_bBag.IsEmpty)
        {
            Guid key = _bBag.Keys.FirstOrDefault();
            int gotB = 0;
            if (_bBag.TryRemove(key, out gotB))
            {
                b = gotB;
                Monitor.PulseAll(gate);
            }
        }
    }

    message = new Message(a, b);
    return message;
}

public Message WrapB(int b, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    Guid key = Guid.NewGuid();
    _bBag.TryAdd(key, b);
    mre.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout);    // use a manual reset instead of Monitor
    int storedB = 0;
    if (_bBag.TryRemove(key, out storedB))
    {
        return new Message(null, b);
    }
    return null;
}
```

All in all, I'd say that you already have a very fine-tuned solution given the tight requirements. I actually hope I'm wrong and someone finds a better solution - it'll be very informative!